# REgex for non repeating alphabets comma seperated

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a requirement where I need a regex which

1. should not repeat alphabet
2. should only contain alphabet and comma
3. should not start or end with comma
4. can contain more than 2 alphabets

example :-

```
A,B     --- correct  
A,B,C,D,E,F --- correct  
D,D,A   --- wrong  
,B,C    --- wrong  
B,C,    --- wrong  
A,,B,C    --- wrong
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Is `A,B,C`also valid?

Comment: yes it is valid

Comment: What about `A,B,A`? Still invalid?

Comment: What do you mean by "can contain more than 2 alphabets"? Also, are non-consecutive repeated letters allowed, like `A,B,A`, or is this forbidden too?

Comment: Why haven't you answered the questions above? Did you just disappear 7+ hours ago?

Answer (score 2):

Another idea with *capturing* and checking by use of a *lookahead*:

```
^(?:([A-Z])(?!.*?\1),?\b)+$
```

You can [test here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CIupRx/1) if it meets your requirements.

If you don't want to match single characters, e.g. `A`, change the `+` *quantifier* to `{2,}`.

Answer (score 2):

The statement of the question is incomplete in several respects. I have made the following assumptions:

1. Considering that `D,D,A` is incorrect I assume that a letter cannot be followed by a comma followed by the same letter.
2. The string may contain the same letter more than once as long as #1 is satisfied.
3. Considering that `A,,B,C` is incorrect I assume a comma cannot follow a comma.
4. Since the examples contain only capital letters I will assume that lower-case letters are not permitted (though one need only set the case-indifferent flag (`i`) to permit either case).

We observe that the requirements are satisfied if and only if the string begins with a capital letter and is followed by a sequence of comma-capital letter pairs, provided that no capital letter is followed by a comma followed by the same letter. We therefore can attempt to match the following regular expression.

```
^(?:([A-Z]),(?!\1))*[A-Z]$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7kbnfY/1)

The elements of the expression are as follows.

```
^          # match beginning of string
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
  ([A-Z])  # match a capital letter and save to capture group 1
  ,        # match a comma
  (?!\1)   # use negative lookahead to assert next character is not equal
           # to the content of capture group 1
)*         # end non-capture group and execute it zero or more times
[A-Z]      # match a capital letter
$          # match end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a big ugly regex solution:

```js
var inputs = ['A,B', 'D,D,D', ',B,C', 'B,C,', 'A,,B'];
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    if (/^(?!.*?([^,]+).*,\1(?:,|$))[^,]+(?:,[^,]+)*$/.test(inputs[i])) {
        console.log(inputs[i] + " => VALID");
    }
    else {
        console.log(inputs[i] + " => INVALID");
    }
}
```

The regex has two parts to it.  It uses a negative lookahead to assert that no two CSV entries ever repeat in the input.  Then, it uses a straightforward pattern to match any proper CSV delimited input.  Here is an explanation:

```regex
^                               from the start of the input
    (?!.*?([^,]+).*,\1(?:,|$))  assert that no CSV element ever repeats
    [^,]+                       then match a CSV element
    (?:,[^,]+)*                 followed by comma and another element, 0 or more times
$                               end of the input
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, It does work, however it only work for 2 alphabets, I am sorry I should have added one point to my question that it can contain more than 2 alphabets.

Can you help me with that ?

Comment: @Nitesh I edited a few times since my initial post.  The answer should work for any number of CSV elements.  You might have to reload your page.

Answer (score 0):

This one could suit your needs:

```
^(?!,)(?!.*,,)(?!.*(\b[A-Z]+\b).*\1)[A-Z,]+(?<!,)$
```

- `^`: the start of the string

  - `(?!,)`: should not be directly followed by a comma
  - `(?!.*,,)`: should not be followed by two commas
  - `(?!.*(\b[A-Z]+\b).*\1)`: should not be followed by a value found twice
- `[A-Z,]+`: should contain letters and commas only
- `$`: the end of the string

  - `(?<!,)`: should not be directly preceded by a comma

See https://regex101.com/r/1kGVSB/1